# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'is_special_taken' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know what is causing this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'is_special_taken'to data type int.

The T-SQL code is:

```
select 
    O.id, O.title, O.type, O.points, O.icon, O.date, 
    COALESCE((select top 1 OAL.offer_id 
              from offer_accepted_log OAL 
              where O.id = OAL.offer_id 
                and OAL.customer_id = @customer_id 
                and O.type = 2), 0) as 'is_special_taken'
from 
    offer O 
where 
    'is_special_taken' = 0
order by 
    O.[date] desc
```

Comment: You have single quotes around the column name.  Hence it is a string.  I vote to close such questions as a simple typographical error.  What a good advertisement for my advice to *never* use single quotes around column names; only use single quotes for strings and date constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I voted to close, I want to point out a simpler way of expressing what I believe the intention of this query is:

```
select O.id, O.title, O.type, O.points, O.icon, O.date, 
from offer O
where not exists (select 1
                  from offer_accepted_log OAL
                  where O.id = OAL.offer_id and
                        OAL.customer_id = @customer_id and
                        O.type = 2
                 )
order by O.[date] desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that column alias can't be used in a where clause.